# Пунктуация во фразе "броня крепка, и танки наши быстры"

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология

Как правильно пишется фраза:

> броня крепка, и танки наши быстры

С формальной точки зрения запятая перед *и* нужна, но по факту встречается [написание без запятой](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B). Рассудите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая перед И нужна, так как это сложносочинённое предложение.

*Броня крепка, и танки наши быстры.*

Отсутствие запятой в некоторых текстах можно объяснить тем, что фраза воспринимается как устойчивое выражение, фразеологизм:

БРОНЯ́ КРЕПКА́ И ТА́НКИ НА́ШИ БЫ́СТРЫ

Используется для выражения уверенности в своей победе или успехе, при этом не обязательно в военном смысле. [Происхождение, значение и употребление афоризма «Броня крепка, и танки наши быстры».](http://fraze.ru/index.php/aforizm/aforizmy-na-bukvu-b/bronya-krepka-i-tanki-nashi-bystry)